# Show RSTP stream on Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to show an RSTP stream from an IP camera, on my Windows form (.NET). But how do I do that?

Most of the articles on Google are on how to show it on a Webpage and/or using VLC.

I have looked at VLC but couldn't compile it, using the many console programs/commands.

Is there a .Net library to show live RSTP stream??

Comment: just in case - you read this article ?   http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3001/how-to-implement-onvif-ip-camera-service-and-rtsp-streaming-to-smartph

Comment: I have now, but i can't connect.. It says authentication failed, but VLC connects perfectly, with the same credentials.. So it doesn't seem to work 100%...